# ASP.NET MVC Controller Factory life cycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

The `DefaultControllerFactory` contains three different methods:

1. `GetControllerInstance`
2. `CreateController`
3. `GetControllerType`

When is each method executed in the request lifetime? I've seen custom controller factories where one of these methods is overridden and implemented but I can't seem to find details on the execution path of each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateController` gets called.
It first calls `GetControllerType` to figure out type of the controller, then passes this type to `GetControllerInstance`.

Because it is easier (and often enough) to (only) override `GetControllerInstance` (so that the logic behind selecting the type remains the same), you'd often see this happening.

Answer (score 1):

Update for MVC3, the methods are called in this order.

`GetControllerType` gets called first and gets called twice.

1. `GetControllerType`
2. `GetControllerSessionBehavior`
3. `CreateController`
4. `GetControllerType`
5. `CreateControllerInstance`
6. `ReleaseController`